# What changes do I need to make for the header file and a cpp file of a 1d array so that it also works for a 2d array?

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, multidimensional-array

Noob at c++ please go easy on the explanations:
Here, I have created a header file and a cpp file which has a few methods that allows to change array size/ delete contents etc for 1d array. The target is to make a few changes so that it also works for 2d arrays. What changes do i need to make here? The user will specify the number of rows and columns also array contents from the main function, which i can do. so-

**The header file:**

```
#ifndef DYNARR_H_INCLUDED
#define DYNARR_H_INCLUDED

class dynArr {
    private:
    int *data;
    int size;

    public:
    dynArr();
    dynArr(int);
    ~dynArr();
    void setValue(int, int);
    int getValue(int);
    void allocate(int); 
};

#endif // DYNARR_H_INCLUDED
```

**The CPP File**

```
#include "dynarr.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
dynArr::dynArr()
{
    data = NULL;
    size = 0;
}
dynArr::dynArr(int s)
{
    data =  new int[s];
    size = s;
}
dynArr::~dynArr()
{
    delete [] data;
}
int dynArr::getValue(int index)
{
    return data[index];
}
void dynArr::setValue(int index, int value)
{
    data[index] = value;
}


void dynArr::allocate(int s)        //allows to change array size
{
    delete [] data;
    data = new int[s];
    size = s;
}
```

Comment: Have you attempted to make the changes you're asking about?  If so then [edit] the question to show your effort and the explain the problems you have with it.

Comment: Why are you not using `std::vector<int>`?  Taking on the task of implementing a dynamic array that actually works correctly is not trivial for anyone new to C++.  If you were to fix `dynArr`, it should be a template class based on the type, instead of it being hardcoded for `int` types.  Then `dynArr<dynArr<int>>` is how you would create a 2D `dynArr` of `int`.

Comment: You can access a 1d array as a 2d array by using a nice formula:  `1d_index = (row * column_size) + column;`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you'd try to allocate dynamic 2D array (in a single application) yourself before looking at the rest of my answer.

Hint : use a pointer-to-pointer to hold the array.

I'll assume that you want to create a new class (let it be dynArr_2d), then you'll probably need to make the following changes :-

• Make 'data' a pointer-to-pointer-to-int.

• Replace the data member 'size' with two data members of type int (e.g. rows and cols) to store the dimensions of the 2D array.

• The implementation of the two-arg constructor (that replaces the one-arg constructor) should be like this :-

```
dynArr_2d::dynArr_2d(int r, int c) {
    rows = r;
    cols  = c;
    data = new int*[r];  //pointer to array of pointers

    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        data[i] = new int[c]; //each pointer in the array points to an array
    }
} //end constructor
```

Explanation for the constructor :-

You know that a pointer to a certain type can be a pointer to an array of that type, and you also know that a 2D array is an array of arrays.

With this in mind, we now can treat 'data' as a pointer-to(pointer-to-int) i.e. 
can be a pointer to an array of(pointers to int), and each pointer in this array can, in turn, point to an array of int's.

• Now that you have the 2D array allocated, the rest of changes will be quite easy.